# Python IDLE is not launching

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-idle, launcher

[Error screenshot of 'python3 -m idlelib'[] [This is where the idle is located]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xli9m.png)[Sample screen shot of the program here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyaGb.png) I recently deletd my old python program and intsalled a new one but now the Python IDLE is not launching when I click it from the start program. Also tried ruuning as a administartor. But when I open the cmd and type: "python3" I am getting the terminal. But I need to code in the python IDLE.

I have adde the image of the python IDLE, if i click that program the notepad/termiunal is not opening.

Comment: Please add some screenshots of your problem and explain it in detail. Just can't make enough sense out of your problem right now!

Comment: @HuzaifaAzhar sir I have added a Screenshot now, please help me

Comment: Check this Question at Stack overflow:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059162/python-idle-wont-start/54098412#54098412

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are using Windows: Win 10?  If 'python3' opens python, I suspect you installed from the Windows store, rather than python.org.  Did you have a python.org install before?  Windows Store Python is controlled by Microsoft, not Python developers.  However, 'python3 -m idlelib' in Command Prompt should start IDLE.  There is no way to tell what the search window is trying to start if it does not start.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy you are right sir i already had python in my E: drive, then due to some space issues i deleted all the files in my E drive and tried re intsalling python. But remember the main os drie in my PC is "C: DRIVE" not 'E:" , so i had to do custom installation and specify the direction in E:

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I tried ruuning the cmd 'python3 -m idlelib'  and it responded "This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly." Also, I added the error screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. It seems my 1. I haven't added my path in the user variablse and 2. In system variables the path given is wrong. And yes as said by @TerryJanReedy I have installed both microsoft and python.org versions, so I deleted all files and carefully re-installed again.